# How to add header row dynamically in gridview

Tags: c#, sql

I got one enhancement work.

Existing report: Am getting the result for the month. for example

Columns:

```
Date | Hospital name | H1 | H2 | H3
```

New requirement:

I need the report for the month(But in the datewise). for example

```
**Date: 1/1/2013**

Hospital name | H1 | H2 | H3 

**Date: 2/1/2013**

Hospital name | H1 | H2 | H3

----
----
----
----
```

In the above scenario, multiple rows will display for the same Date. so, i don't want to repeat the date, Just display the records below the date..

So, i went for the solution of binding the header row dynamically in the gridview.

So please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as how you're populating your page, your existing ASP.NET markup, what version of ASP.NET you're using, etc.

Comment: What type of application is this, Windows app or Web app? What type of control are you using now display the data, is it a grid view ?  You said you went for the solution, Did you mean you you tried it out and are stuck with some where Or did you mean you dont know how to implement 'your solution' (ie headers dynamically)

Comment: Its Web application version 4.0, and its the Gridview control. I struck with the binding the 'Date' in the header dynamically. And looking for the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using nested Gridview if you want to. And example can be found [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Personally I would just use ListView or Repeater to do that.

Comment: Its really useful.I went with Listview.